# Initialize structures without defining members of structure - C

Tags: c, structure

I am trying to decipher someone's code and I see something that I don't understand.  I don't see any references on how structures are applied when members aren't defined in the header or in the beginning of code but are defined later on..  Here is an example of what I am trying to figure out. I noted that Data_t *data; in the header is not defined until we enter the funky function and my compiler errors out on this line.  I guess my question would be -- is this a valid way to input data into structures?

Much thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct config{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    Data_t *data;
} config_t;

int funky(config_t *config);

int main( void )
{
    printf("In main()\n");
    config_t config;
    funky(&config);

    printf("a = %d\n", config.a);   //accessing config's a member

    return 0;
}

int funky(config_t *config)
{
    printf("In funky()\n");

    Data_t *dataa = config->data;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        dataa[i].mem1=i;
        dataa[i].mem2=4+i;
    }

    //Set values
    config->a = 1;
    printf("a = %d\n", config->a);  //pointer to config's a member

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of `Data_t` doesn't appear in your code, which is what's causing the compile error.

Also - to your specific question, that code is dereferencing an uninitialized pointer, which causes undefined behaviour.  Initialize the `data` field in the `config` structure in `main`, or you're going to be in trouble.  This block of code:

```
Data_t *dataa = config->data;
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    dataa[i].mem1=i;
    dataa[i].mem2=4+i;
}
```

Is the bad stuff - as you can see, it copies the unitialized pointer out and tries to access memory through it.

The code after that:

```
//Set values
config->a = 1;
```

Is fine, and a totally reasonable way to initialize a structure.

Comment: Hi Carl, Thanks for the quick response.  So, if I initialize the data field in the config structure in main, it should be ok, right?  The code that I am looking at as reference says that in their main() code, they did something like config.data=calloc(NUM,sizeof(Data_t)); I don't understand how the compiler would know what the size of Data_t is when it isn't really defined.  (?? O_O ??)  Thanks..

Comment: That should fix you up, yes.  It won't fix the compiler error due to `Data_t` not being defined, but assuming you have that cleared up, initializing that pointer is also important.

Comment: How would you go about defining Data_t?  The way I see it, if you define Data_t i.e. typedef struct dataS{ int mem1; int mem2; } Data_t in the header or in main, then you don't need to do Data_t *dataa = config->data; in the funky function.  Which goes back to one of the earlier quesions - is it possible to define members of the structure in functions when it needs to make a member?